Redirecting to another page after a successful user log in
Subject: Assistance with User Authentication for Page Access
Hi,
I’m having trouble implementing a solution to restrict access to a page so that only authenticated users can view it. In my previous content management system, I used a .htaccess file to redirect users to a login page. Depending on their authentication status, they would then be redirected either to the intended page or receive a warning message and be sent back.
I have a content page with <a href=""> link to /memberpage, and I’d like users to be taken to the login page when they click it. If they authenticate successfully, they would be redirected to a different page; if not, they would see a warning message and return to the previous page.
Could you please guide me on how to implement this?
Thanks!
J

Have you checked this resource mzg?
Note:

You can customize where users should get redirected to after login via the postLoginRedirect config setting.

Then for any pages or templates you want to password protect you would add the following:
{# Require that a user is logged in to view this form. #}
{% requireLogin %}

Hope that helps,
Cole

I haven't seen it before but I'll try it.  Thank you!
